# How to get the references of all opened child windows after parent window reload

Tags: javascript, window, parent, reload

I am storing the reference of child window in variable as below.

```
var mychildWindow = window.open(url,name,params);
```

When the parent window refresh/reload how to get the child window instance??

Any work around or like Facebook did for pop out chat.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would call this one "How to preserve javascript handle of child window during parent page reload?". I'm surprised that there is no interest in this question, I would expect many standard workarounds...

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't use (to my knowledge) window.open - they use panels - floating divs a layer above the main content - have a look at the YUI Panel for an example.

Comment: I think it is not the floating divs, they are loading /popout.html in that window

Answer (score -1):

If you have control over both windows, the child window can send a beacon to the parent on an interval: "I'm your child, I'm your child, I'm your child".

http://abcoder.com/javascript/maintain-reference-to-popup-window-over-page-refresh-or-redirect-in-javascript-solved

Unfortunately, I'm opening potentially any url in the child window, so I don't have control over that.